# Waiting For response of call Web Service

Tags: ios, swift, closures, grand-central-dispatch

I have an array of string for translate, I want to call Yandex translate API for each string in array create sentence from this translate results, and then pass this sentence in closure to controller and update UI.I want to when my sentence was made pass complete sentence in closure but now I check index of array count for call closure, I want a better solution for this.

```
class TranslateService {
  private let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
  func translateText(text:[String],closure:@escaping ((_ success:String?,_ error:Error?) -> Void)) {

    var translateString: String = ""
    var responseError: Error?

    for index in 0...text.count - 1 {
      myGroup.enter()
      let urlString = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20171105T134956Z.795c7a0141d3061b.dc25bae76fa5740b2cdecb02396644dea58edd24&text=\(text[index])&lang=fa&format=plain&options=1"
      if let allowString = Utilities.shareInstance.getQueryAllowedString(url: urlString) {
        if let url = URL(string:allowString){
          Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
            guard let responseData = response.data else {
              return
            }
            do {
              let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])
              if let res = json as? [String:Any] {
                if let code = res["code"] as? Int {
                  if code == 200 {
                    if let textArr = res["text"] as? [AnyObject] {
                      let flattArr = Utilities.shareInstance.flatStringMapArray(textArr)
                      if flattArr.count > 0 {
                        translateString += "،" + flattArr[0]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }catch {
              responseError = error
            }

            if index == text.count - 1 {
              closure(translateString, responseError)
              self.myGroup.leave()
            }
          }
          self.myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("Finished all requests.")
          }
        }
      }

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Does that code even work? You enter in dispatch group using `myGroup.enter()` multiple times (based on number of strings in array) and leave only when `index == text.count - 1` that will happen only once, so basically if there is more than one string in array your code will never be notified and will never execute closure

Comment: Take a look at the answer posted below. Lemme know if its of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, There is absolutely no need to compare index.I think you have misunderstood the concept of dispatch group

```
class TranslateService {
        private let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
        func translateText(text:[String],closure:@escaping ((_ success:String?,_ error:Error?) -> Void)) {

            var translateString: String = ""
            var responseError: Error?

            for index in 0...text.count - 1 {
                let urlString = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20171105T134956Z.795c7a0141d3061b.dc25bae76fa5740b2cdecb02396644dea58edd24&text=\(text[index])&lang=fa&format=plain&options=1"
                if let allowString = Utilities.shareInstance.getQueryAllowedString(url: urlString) {
                    if let url = URL(string:allowString){
                        myGroup.enter()
                        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
                            guard let responseData = response.data else {
                                myGroup.leave()
                                return
                            }
                            do {
                                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])
                                if let res = json as? [String:Any] {
                                    if let code = res["code"] as? Int {
                                        if code == 200 {
                                            if let textArr = res["text"] as? [AnyObject] {
                                                let flattArr = Utilities.shareInstance.flatStringMapArray(textArr)
                                                if flattArr.count > 0 {
                                                    translateString += "،" + flattArr[0]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                myGroup.leave()
                            }catch {
                                responseError = error
                                myGroup.leave()
                            }
                        }
                        self.myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                            print("Finished all requests.")
                            closure(translateString, responseError)
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Dispatch group notify block will be executed only when all the async tasks that entered the group leaves the block. So you can execute your closure in notify block. That should give u a clear indication that all alamofire requests finished either successfully or with error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank's for reply, I change my code and that is work well.

Comment: @ava : Am glad I could be of help :) Happy coding